# OpenVas + Kali Rolling: The connection was reset

Tags: linux, debian, networking, security, kali-linux

I am trying to get OpenVAS to work in the latest Kali release (rolling).

It seems to be installed right, but when I try to access the web interface (`127.0.0.1:9392`), I get `Connection was reset`.

```
openvas-check-setup output http://pastebin.com/dR3rpuL1

netstat -antp output http://pastebin.com/xSD6eYra
```

**Note:** I am running kali in Vmware workstation.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  If it is being served over SSL (likely), you may have to explicitly specify `https://` before `127.0.0.1:9392` so your full URL is:

```
https://127.0.0.1:9392
```